# Deselect all listview items on scrollstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

When you scroll the page, and start that scroll by pressing on a listview button, the button remains highlighted for the scroll and stays highlighted after the scroll has finished. How can I deselect this when the scroll starts?

It works if I do this:

```
$(document).bind('scrollstart', function(ev) {
    $('*').blur();
});
```

But this is inefficient and causes the page to lag before scrolling starts, I've tried bluring just `a`, `li`, `ui-btn` and `ui-li`, but this doesn't unhighlight it.

Comment: what is listview button? [Focus selector](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) - have you tried this?

Comment: Uh. Sorry. Jquery mobile. But still - focus selector may be useful

Comment: Is helpful thanks, although I tried the above code but with `$('*:focus').blur();` instead but that doesn't unhighlight anything, strange.

Comment: Have you checked this:  "If you are looking for the currently focused element, $( document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree."? $('*:focus') - this works the same as your code, according to jquery docs(in both cases all elements are searched).So there should be no difference. But document.activeElement looks very interesting to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on a list-item on a jQuery Mobile pseudo-page, you're basically adding the `ui-btn-down-*` class to the list-item (the `*` denotes one of the theme letters).

You can remove this class once the user starts scrolling, here is an example:

```
$(document).on("scrollstart", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-li').removeClass('ui-btn-down-a ui-btn-down-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-down-d ui-btn-down-e');
    }, 100);
});​
```

**UPDATE**

Testing on my Droid X I found that a timeout helped take-away the highlighted state more consistently. You can mess with the duration of the timeout for your own purpose.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WrqbG/7/

**UPDATE**

I also realized that the `.ui-btn-hover-*` class is applied, so to return to an un-highlighted list you've got to remove those classes as well.

```
.removeClass('ui-btn-down-a ui-btn-down-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-down-d ui-btn-down-e')
```

Just changes to:

```
.removeClass('ui-btn-down-a ui-btn-down-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-down-d ui-btn-down-e ui-btn-hover-a  ui-btn-hover-b  ui-btn-hover-c  ui-btn-hover-d  ui-btn-hover-e')
```